# Count distinct values in report

Tags: crystal-reports, report

My report needs to count the number of vehicles that come into the station each day. I created a group for the date field and made formula which takes that result. It counts records, but it counts previous days as well:

```
date       vno    vehile_type  job_done
1/3/2017   aa123   hero          cha
1/3/2017   aa123   hero          cha
1/3/2017   aa123   herohonda     cha
```

> no of hero:2  no of herohonda :1

```
2/3/2017   aa123   hero          cha
2/3/2017   aa123   herohonda     cha
2/3/2017   aa123   herohonda     cha
```

> no of hero:3  no of herohonda :3

this is my formula

### for "count1" formula

```
numbervar totalcount;
If {vehicle.vtype} = "HeroHonda" then
    totalcount := totalcount +1
else
totalcount := totalcount
```

---

### for count2 formula

```
numbervar totalcount1;
If {vehicle.vtype} = "Hero" then
    totalcount1 := totalcount1 +1
else
    totalcount1 := totalcount1
```

---

i need to get the result like the following

```
date       vno    vehile_type  job_done
1/3/2017   aa123   hero          cha
1/3/2017   aa123   hero          cha
1/3/2017   aa123   herohonda     cha
```

> no of hero:2  no of herohonda :1

```
2/3/2017   aa123   hero          cha
2/3/2017   aa123   herohonda     cha
2/3/2017   aa123   herohonda     cha
```

> no of hero:1  no of herohonda :2

Answer (score 0):

From what you have provided i see that you have group `date` so only thing you miss for this to work properly is to reset your variables for each day. You need to make 2 new formulas which will reset for each day your variables which you are later showing in group footer (i suppose).

Make new formula `reset1`

```
numbervar totalcount:=0;
```

and `reset2`

```
numbervar totalcount1:=0;
```

and place them in your group header of field `date` so they reset for each day. Suppress them so they don't show on actual report but do the behind logic for making counts.

Hope it helps

Comment: thank bro for your help. i try it but it still the same . it not cout new number of vehicle on next day .same result like the above .it hold previous count and it forward to the next day cout know, i need count vehicle for each day  only.

Comment: Where have you placed your formulas? In which section?

Comment: i add that newly created formula on date group header section

Comment: Yes, but your existing formula needs to be placed into detail section, to make counts properly

Comment: bro i need another help from you.
 i have a data gridview i load access data on it,  i have a column  with name "Bick Type" .in that column has two different type of bick, called "hond" and "herohonda".in this column that bick type enter several times becous its a service tabe. so need to count how many hond entry and how many herohonda entry are there and need that two count in two text box separetly when i press botton.

Comment: Did this answer helped you to solve your asked question? If yes then accept this answer and ask your second problem in separate question.